# Maximum amount of batch deletes in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find out if the `500` amount mentioned in the `batched writes` section applies to `delete` as well?

Looked through `Usage and Limits`, nothing mentioned there. Can anyone let us know if there's any limit to that kind of operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of 500 operations in a batch applies to any write operations in that batch: updates, reads, and deletes.

Comment: Ok cool. Only asked because in the docs, that `500` limit was only found under `batched writes`.

Comment: Creates, deletes, and updates are all write operations.